# How to redirect to the last visited page in Grails app?

Tags: grails, redirect, authentication

I am a newbie in Grails and I am struggling with many simple issues.

For instance, I haven't managed to find a proper way to go back to the last visited page when I login/logout from a template view that is displayed on the top layout of the page.

My last attempt at solving this problem was to save the ${params.controller} and ${params.action} in the parameters sent to the logout action and redirect thereafter. Well...even this failed.
Here is the gsp snippet:

```
<g:link controller="user" action="logout" params="[currentController: ${params.controller}, currentAction: ${params.action}]">Logout</g:link>
```

This last code line throws the following exception:

```
ERROR errors.GrailsExceptionResolver  - Error evaluating expression [[currentController: ${params.controller}, currentAction: ${params.action}]]
```

So my questions are:

1 - How can I reload the last visited page after a login/logout action ?

2 - Why do I have an exception from my code above?

Thank You

EDIT :
Concerning question #2, it seems that the following code is working:

```
<g:link controller="user" action="logout" params="[currentController: params.controller, currentAction: params.action]">Logout</g:link>
```

But I don't really understand the reason...

EDIT2 : 
I have also found out a solution for redirecting to the last visited page:

```
redirect(url: request.header('referer'))
```

But unfortunately when doing this after login, the contents rendered in my page are duplicated. Any idea or any other safe solution?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The easiest way to redirect to the last page, is to use the URI directly:

```
<g:link controller="user" action="logout" params="[targetUri: (request.forwardURI - request.contextPath)]">Logout</g:link>
```

(`request.forwardURI` is the complete URL as displayed in the browser, while `request.contextPath` is the URL part representing the app context, eg. "http://localhost:8080/yourApp" - thus, the result of removing the context path from the forward URI is the app-relative URI, eg. "/mycontroller/myaction")

In your logout action simply redirect to this URI:

```
def targetUri = params.targetUri ?: "/"
redirect(uri: targetUri)
```

AFAIK, using the referrer is not entirely safe, because this relies on the user agent (browser) to append the referrer HTTP header (which may have been disabled).

**As to your 2nd question:** Grails automatically interprets list or map attribute values in GSPs as Groovy expressions. So, this

```
<g:link controller="user" action="logout" params="[currentController: params.controller, currentAction: params.action]">Logout</g:link>
```

is equivalent to

```
<g:link controller="user" action="logout" params="${[currentController: params.controller, currentAction: params.action]}">Logout</g:link>
```

and wrapping parts of this expression again in `${...}` seems to confuse the GSP compiler.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Daniel,

Thank you very much for your aswer. You helped me a lot !!

Comment: @daniel-rinser  Your answer only seems to work through a single refresh.  How would you suggest handling the following:  
  Page0->Page1  
  Enter data in form w/errors  
  Redirected back to Page1 with flash.errors  
  Enter data in form correctly  
  Should get redirected back to Page0  
  Instead get sent to '/' as request.forwardURI() / targetURI is ""

Comment: Why have the app relative URI? What's the problem with the complete Url?

Answer (score 39):

I'm using this controller-side:

```
    redirect(uri: request.getHeader('referer') )
```

Answer (score 3):

In GSP view file you can use as such.

```
<g:link url="${request.getHeader('referer')}"> Back </g:link>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is to build the url with [createLink](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/3.0.x/ref/Tags/createLink.html) using the current: [actionName](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/3.0.0/ref/Controllers/actionName.html), [controllerName](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/3.0.x/ref/Controllers/controllerName.html) and [params](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/3.0.x/ref/Controllers/params.html).

```
<g:link controller="user" action="logout" params="[targetUri: createLink(controller: controllerName, action:actionName, params:params, absolute:true)]">Logout</g:link>
```

This will create an absolute url, because of the `absolute:true`.