# Is there a simple way of redirecting in a Grails controller to the previous URL?

Tags: grails, redirect, controller

I have a grails controller action which changes some internal state for the user, but should then return the user to the page he was on prevously.  This page will look a little different due to the change of state, but is there a simple way to redirect to an arbitrary previous page?

E.g.

```
class MyController {
    changeSomething() {
        // ... change something here ...
        redirect controller:request.controller,
                action:request.action,
                params:request.params
    }
}
```

Comment: This topic looks similar:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1451314/how-to-redirect-to-the-last-visited-page-in-grails-app

Comment: @Tom it does indeed - thank you